# Having issues with discord bot and cogs using python

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

New to discord bots having issue with loading cogs looking for some guidance

bot.py

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready to be used!")

@bot.command()
async def load_extension(ctx, extension_name):
    try:
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension_name}')
        await ctx.send(f'Extension {extension_name} loaded.')
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f'Error loading extension: {e}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

    bot.run(token)
```

cogs/newgame.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from random import randrange

class NewGameCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def newgame(self, ctx):
        # Game logic  

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(NewGameCog(bot))
```

I am getting runtime warnings that I cant seem to fix

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2023-10-18 01:54:39 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2023-10-18 01:54:40 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: hidden).
Bot is ready to be used!
```

I can get everything to work properly in bot.py file without cogs

Having issues once I change the code to add cogs like code above

Comment: Not fully sure, but maybe you need to `await` the async in cogs?

Answer (score 0):

`bot.load_extension` is an asynchronous function and has to be awaited. Simply,

```
await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension_name}')
```

Asynchronous functions can only be awaited inside of asynchronous functions.

```
async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await load_extensions()
```

Comment: do that I get this `await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function` put it in function get different error keep going down different rabbit holes

Comment: You can put it in a separate asynchronous function and call it in the `on_ready` event

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way to go about it.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from cogs.newgame import NewGameCog

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready to be used!")

    newgame_cog = NewGameCog(bot)
    await bot.add_cog(newgame_cog)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I load my cogs:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir('PATH_TO_COG_FOLDER'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            i += 1
            cog_name = filename[:-3]
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog_name}')
    print(f"Loaded {i} cogs")
```

Note: *My cogs are in a folder named cogs that is why I have await **bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog_name}')** if you have it like this too the path has to include the cogs folder too: **some/path/to/cogs***

Comment: I will give this a try to see if I can get this to work for me